# Setting memory breakpoint in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I need to set breakpoint that watches a specific address in memory (e.g. 0x0483d7cc) that is hit when the content changes. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and C++. How can I do that?

Comment: have you read Visual Studio documentation? You just need to press F1 in VS

Comment: This won't help you much as addresses will definitely change thanks to ASLR & Co.

Comment: Good point. But in my case, I am working with images and want to know what function modified a given pixel. The data are already allocated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use  the menu item: `Debug | New Breakpoint | New Data Breakpoint...`